# How to change the font size for sap.m.Label without custom CSS?

Tags: sapui5

How to change the font size for sap.m.Label without CSS.

```xml
<Label text="NAME" />
```

Comment: Changing the size of a label without custom CSS is currently not supported unless you use other controls such as [sap.m.Title](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Title.html#constructor) which allows us to change the [size](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Title.html#setTitleStyle).

Comment: This is quite an unusual request in UI5. We have to know what you're actually trying to achieve. But it's missing from the question.

Answer (score -2):

Only way to change Label Font size is by using a custom CSS file.

1. Add a n ew folder under webapp and name it "css".
2. Add a file called "style.css" under the new folder.
3. Add the following style in style.css :

```css
.myApp .smallLabel {
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

4. Apply the style on your label :

```html
    <App class="myApp">
      <pages>
         <Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}">
            <content>
               <Panel>
                  <content>
                     <Label text="{path: 'Recipes>Title'}" class="smallLabel"/>
                  </content>
               </Panel>
            </content>
         </Page>
      </pages>
    </App>
```

Comment: There were already many answers (now deleted) suggesting to use CSS. The question author, however, explicitly asked **without CSS.** He knows that there is currently no way other than using custom CSS.